# Append custom shipping address attribute to API V2 wsdl result

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2, shipping-address

I added the Dhl Account module in my magento 1.9.2.4 installation to get the possibility to ship to a dhl packing station. The module appends a field called `dhlaccount` to the shipping address of an order.

Now I have the problem that this field does not exist in the `salesOrderInfo` API request. Is there a way to append a custom shipping address field to the API result?

Thanks in advance!

**Install script**

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

/* @var $addressHelper Mage_Customer_Helper_Address */
$addressHelper = Mage::helper('customer/address');

// update customer address user defined attributes data
$attributes = array(
    'dhlaccount' => array(
        'backend_type'    => 'varchar',
        'backend_model'   => '',
        'backend_table'   => '',
        'frontend_model'  => '',
        'frontend_input'  => 'text',
        'frontend_label'  => 'DHL Account',
        'frontend_class'  => '',
        'source_model'    => '',
        'default_value'   => '',
        'is_user_defined' => 1,
        'is_system'       => 0,
        'is_visible'      => 1,
        'sort_order'      => 140,
        'is_required'     => 0,
        'multiline_count' => 0,
        'validate_rules'  => array(
            'max_text_length' => 10,
            'min_text_length' => 6
        ),
    ),

);

/* @var $eavConfig Mage_Eav_Model_Config */
$eavConfig = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
foreach ($attributes as $attributeCode => $data) {
    $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode);
    $attribute->addData($data);
    $usedInForms = array(
        'adminhtml_customer_address',
        'customer_address_edit',
        'customer_register_address'
    );
    $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $usedInForms);
    $attribute->save();
}

$installer->run("
    ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('sales_flat_quote_address')} ADD COLUMN `dhlaccount` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL AFTER `fax`;
    ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('sales_flat_order_address')} ADD COLUMN `dhlaccount` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL AFTER `fax`;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: if you mean the code which appends the attribute, I added it.

Comment: did you also updated the config.xml of your module for this new attribute under `sales_convert_quote`  and `sales_convert_quote_address` ?

Comment: It isn't my module. It's a module from DHL which can be found here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dhl-intraship-versenden.html. But yes, the attribute is appended coorectly in the config.xml

Comment: Where can I locate this method or reference `salesOrderInfo `  in the module?

Comment: also check if the attribute is allowed. how are you calling the api?